# Dropzone multiple en formulario

Tags: jquery, laravel, blade, dropzone, dropzone.js

Tengo este código en mi plantilla blade donde declaro dos div con distintos ids, para identificar cada uno con un dropzone.

```
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div  id="dropzoneEsp" class="col-md-6">
                    {!! Form::open([ 'route' => [ 'dropzone.store' ], 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'image-upload1' ]) !!}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="buttonImagenCat" class="btn btn-primary">Subir imagen (cat)</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                <div  id="dropzoneCat" class="col-md-6">
                    {!! Form::open([ 'route' => [ 'dropzone.store' ], 'files' => true, 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'class' => 'dropzone', 'id' => 'image-upload2' ]) !!}

                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="buttonImagenEsp" class="btn btn-primary">Subir imagen (esp)</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Y luego con Jquery intento construir este código para darle una funcionalidad a cada uno, siguiendo este código

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myDropzoneTheFirst = new Dropzone(
        //id of drop zone element 1
        '#dropzoneCat', {
            url : "uploadUrl/1"
        }
    );

    var myDropzoneTheSecond = new Dropzone(
        //id of drop zone element 2
        '#dropzoneEsp', {
            url : "uploadUrl/2"
        }
    );

    myDropzoneTheFirst.options.imageUpload = {
        maxFiles: 1,
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        accept: function(file, done) {
            console.log("uploaded");
            done();
        },
        init: function() {

            var myDropzoneESP = this;

            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                alert("No more files please!");
            });

            // Update selector to match your button
            $("#buttonImagenEsp").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzoneESP.processQueue();
            });

            this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                if (this.files[1] != null) {
                    //alert('add file');
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                }
            });
        },
    };
```

No se si lo planteo bien en el JavaScript, lo que intento hacer es definir dos objetos dropzone y luego intento asignarle a cada uno unas características.

Comment: Pero te da algún error tu desarrollo? En que podemos ayudarte?

Answer (score 2):

Al final lo he solucionado , instanciando 2 componentes dropzone js de esta forma

```
    Dropzone.options.drozponeEsp = {
        maxFiles: 1,
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        accept: function(file, done) {
            buttonImagenEsp = true;
            done();
        },
        init: function() {

            var myDropzoneESP = this;

            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                alert("No more files please!");
            });

            // Update selector to match your button
            $("#buttonImagenEsp").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzoneESP.processQueue();
            });

            this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                if (this.files[1] != null) {
                    //alert('add file');
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                }
            });

            this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
                imageEsp = '';
            });

            this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
                imageEsp = responseText.image;
            });

        },
    };



    Dropzone.options.drozponeCat = {
        maxFiles: 1,
        addRemoveLinks : true,
        autoProcessQueue: false,
        accept: function(file, done) {
            buttonImagenCat = true;
            done();
        },
        init: function() {

            var myDropzoneCat = this;

            this.on("maxfilesexceeded", function(file){
                alert("No more files please!");
            });

            // Update selector to match your button
            $("#buttonImagenCat").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                myDropzoneCat.processQueue();
            });

            this.on("addedfile", function (file) {
                if (this.files[1] != null) {
                    //alert('add file');
                    this.removeFile(this.files[0]);
                }
            });

            this.on("removedfile", function (file) {
                imageCat = '';
            });

            this.on("success", function (file, responseText) {
                console.log(responseText.image);
                imageCat = responseText.image;
                console.log('imageCat  ' + imageCat);
            });

        },
    };
```